# Having trouble deploying database to kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am able to deploy the database service itself, but when I try to deploy with a persistent volume claim as well, the deployment silently fails. Below is the `deployment.yaml` file I am using. The service deploys fine if I remove the first 14 lines that define the persistent volume claim.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: timescale-pvc-1
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  storageClassName: standard
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: timescale
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: timescale
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: timescale
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: timescale
        image: timescale/timescaledb:2.3.0-pg11
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
              - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                value: "password"
              - name: POSTGRES_DB
                value: "metrics"
      volumes:
        - name: timescaledb-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: timescale-pvc-1
```

Comment: With a setup like this, a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) might be a little better match than a Deployment plus a PersistentVolumeClaim.  A StatefulSet will automatically create the PVC for you (you embed a template), which means you can have multiple replicas (assuming the application understands this).  When you say "the deployment silently fails", how can you tell?

Comment: I see two ansers and one comment suggesting to use statefulsets .... I would be curious to understand how is this relevant here. Question is about a pod that "silently fails": all we need to know is: what lead you to this observations, can you share pod logs (kubectl logs -p, to see logs for a container that exited/restarts)? events in your namespace (kubectl get events)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider StatefulSet for running stateful apps like databases. Deployment is preferred for stateless services.

You are using the below storage class in the PVC.

```
storageClassName: standard
```

Ensure the storage class supports dynamic storage provisioning.

Answer (score -1):

Are you creating a PV along with PVC and Deployment? A Deployment, Stateful set or a Pod can only use PVC if there is a PV available.

If you're creating the PV as well then there's a possibility of a different issue. Please share the logs of your Deployment and PVC